# Duplicate entry '' for key 'Correo'

Tags: mysql, sql-server, web, aplicación-web, insert

Espero que me puedan ayudar tengo problema con este error al hacer ina insercion de datos desde una paguina web pero no tengo ni idea del por que me aparece.
estoy usando un host atraves de navicat, y genero la tabla con sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `Correo` varchar(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `NombreAgui` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `DescNom` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ArchDib` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `DescDib` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar, no tento nada con auto_increment, y la tabla de echbo esta vacia y me csale este error "Duplicate entry '' for key 'Correo'" ni si queira en las comillas sale ningun valor.

Comment: Como puedes ver `Correo` tiene una restricción `UNIQUE`, significa que no podrá haber más de dos `Correo` iguales en la tabla. Cuando salta ese mensaje es porque intentas insertar un `Correo` que ya existe. Antes de insertar debes verificar si no existe.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero no esta haciendo nisiqueira la insercion de datos en la base de datos a pesar de que es un correo diferente

Comment: ¿Tu que crees que sea? @A.Cedano

Comment: `Duplicate entry for key 'Correo'` no tiene otra explicación, significa que estás intentando ingresar un `Correo` que ya existe sí o sí.

Comment: Si tienes razon, pero ya vi cual era el problema, resulta que se me olvido poner el method en el formulario de tipo post, lo cual no c por que de todos modos me lansaba ese error. Por que cheque mi codigo y fue eso pero no entiendo la explicacion del ¿por que?.

Comment: Eso no tiene que ver con lo otro. Si no pones método el form asume el método por defecto. Ese error es muy específico de la base de datos, no tiene que ver con el formulario. Será que pusiste otro valor que no era duplicado y el error desapareció.